# Subequation labeling inside an "aligned" environment

Tags: math-mode, numbering, amsmath

I can align several equations inside a single brace with the following code.

```
\begin{equation}
    \left\lbrace
        \begin{aligned}
            k \cdot E &= 0 \\
            k \cdot B &= 0
        \end{aligned}
    \right.
\end{equation}
```

And I know how to use subequation numbering when I don't put the brace.

```
\begin{subequations}
    \begin{align}
        k \cdot E &= 0 \\
        k \cdot B &= 0
    \end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

But I do not manage to do both.  The following code compiles but does not produce the expected result.

```
\begin{equation}
    \left\lbrace
        \begin{subequations}
            \begin{aligned}
                k \cdot E &= 0 \\
                k \cdot B &= 0
            \end{aligned}
        \end{subequations}
    \right.
\end{equation}
```

Expected:

```
     / k . E = 0     (10a)
    {
     \ k . D = 0     (10b)
```

Actual result:

```
     / k . E = 0
    {                 (11)
     \ k . D = 0
```

And there is nothing with the tag 10.

If I move the `subequations` outside (that is, in order: `subequations`, `equation`, `\left`, `aligned`), then I get the single tag (10).

If I move `subequations` inside `aligned`, it does not compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `empheq` (but first think again if you really need separate numbers):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{9} % just for the example

\begin{subequations}
\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
k \cdot E &= 0 \\
k \cdot B &= 0
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  How does it play with cleveref and hyperef?

Comment: @Niriel Since it internally uses `amsmath`, there should be no problem, but as I rarely use `cleveref` I can't say. Please report any problem.